# Does deleting account from Firebase automatically logs user out?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I would like to know, does deleting account from Firebase automatically logs user out?
 I mean, if I want to show him after deleting the login screen, then I just have to present that VC?
 I am asking this because if I do like this, it crashes and I think it is because the user doesn't exists anymore at this points. 
Am I right?

The code with some explenations :

```
let user = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser

user?.deleteWithCompletion { error in
  if let error = error {
    // An error happened.
  } else {
     try! FIRAuth.auth()!.signOut()//This is unnecessary?

            let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name:"Main",bundle:nil)

            let WelcomeViewController: UIViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "WelcomeViewController")

            //Send the user to the WelcomeViewController
            self.present(WelcomeViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    // Account deleted. 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are deleting your **currentUser** you need to take care of two things:-

- Delete the user's data from the **Firebase Database** (If there is any)
- Delete the auth **Credentials** (e.g :- email-password, facebook login, twitter etc)

  To delete your current user use the below function, which also first sign's out the user

  ```
   FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.delete(completion: { (err) in

      print(err?.localizedDescription)

  })
  ```

  If you CMD+CLICK on the delete function it will take you to its documentation :-

> Deletes the user account (also signs out the user, if this was the current user).
>
> *completion* Optionally; the block invoked when the request to delete the account is complete, or fails. Invoked asynchronously on the main thread in the future.
>
> Possible error codes:
>               - @c FIRAuthErrorCodeRequiresRecentLogin - Updating email is a security sensitive operation that requires a recent login from the user. This error indicates the user has not signed in recently enough. To resolve, reauthenticate the user by invoking reauthenticateWithCredential:completion: on FIRUser.
>
> See @c FIRAuthErrors for a list of error codes that are common to all FIRUser operations.
>        */

So long story short if the ***err*** received is nil your current users's account has not only been deleted but also signed out automatically, But you will need to handle other **FIRAuthErrors** as stated in the documentation

Comment: Then yes you have already signed your user out, automatically.

Comment: But why I am getting the crash after pointing user to welcome view?

Comment: Where exactly do you get the error? In this class or `WelcomeViewController` And at what line?

Comment: If you are accessing current user's info in that class then maybe yes...

Comment: Is this your welcomeViewController code that you just updated? Try changing to `let user = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser` to `if let user = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser {..}`

Comment: How can you delete user data if once account deleted it signs you out and basically permissions are denied to write.?